# Distorted image of KML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth, image, distortion

I just started using QGIS and I used Google Earth to export images as KML ground overlays. I then bring the KML into QGIS, then georeference the raster. I tried using de CRS 6370. However, the image imported into QGIS ends up all distorted. What can I do to make it look like in Google Earth? [image: That's how the image in QGIS looks like]

Comment: You have done something wrong with the georeferencing but you do not explain clear enough what you did so it is hard to help you.

Comment: I added six points in the georeferencing that I had added in Google Earth.

Comment: In transformation type I clicked on Polynomial 2

Comment: Still not enough details. Could you add the table of ground control points and the gdal_translate and gdalwarp commands that QGIS generates for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this experience, and it stopped being a problem when I switched my Qgis projects over to use EPSG:3857 as the CRS.

KML files can only have by default one particular CRS which can't be changed. It is baked into the KML spec. Unless you use a compatible CRS in your Qgis project and layers you will run into problems like this with importing KML into Qgis.

Comment: The only valid CRS for KML is WGS84, EPSG:4326. Have a look at the current specification for more info: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: There's numerous other comments on this site about using EPSG:3857 with KML files. Google Maps uses EPSG:3857. When I used EPSG:4326 with my projects I had the same problem reported by the OP.

Comment: I already tried with EPSG:3857 but the image is still distorted.